# Zoomable Custom Gridview List

Tags: android

I have custom gridview list that is implemented by Baseadapter class. Each grid contains three textviews.
I have my code ready i just want a solution that i want to zoom my whole grid list using ScaleGesture.
After zooming it should scroll in vertical and horizontal directions.
Note:- I don't want it to be zoomed with zoomcontrols

[here is my output's screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMZV3.png)

And this my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Calendar">
        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/dateGrid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numColumns="6"
            >
        </GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Java**

```
  dateGrid.setAdapter(new dateAdapter(Calendar.this,dates));
```

Please help i m new to android and kindly illustrate the answer in more details